# "Error: Field '[REDACTED].field_id' not found on either side of the JOIN", Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

As a beginner to Google's BigQuery platform, I have found it almost similar to MySql regarding its syntax. However, I am receiving an issue with my query where it is not finding a column on either side of the Inner Join I am performing.

A sample query below:

```
SELECT
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.context_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.transaction_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.meta_recordDate,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.transaction_total,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.view_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_view.user_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_view.view_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_view.new_vs_returning,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.view_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.experienceId,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.experienceName,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.variationName,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.iterationId,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.isControl
FROM
  [base_account.random_table_name_transaction] transactiontable
INNER JOIN
  base_account.random_table_name_view viewtable
ON
  transactiontable.view_id=viewtable.view_id
INNER JOIN
  [base_account.random_table_name_experience] experiencetable
ON
  viewtable.view_id=experiencetable.view_id
WHERE experiencetable.experienceId = 96659 or experiencetable.experienceId = 96660
```

In this case, when I run it within the BigQuery platform, after a few seconds of the query running I am returned an error:
`"Error: Field 'base_account.random_table_name_experience.experienceId' not found on either side of the JOIN"`.

However, when I run the same query however I perform a `SELECT *` query, it does execute properly and returns the data I expect.

Is there something missing with my syntax as to why it is failing? I can confirm that each column I am trying to return does exist in each respected table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) for your query to avoid some of the surprising aliasing rules with legacy SQL and to get more informative error messages. Your query would be:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.context_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.transaction_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.meta_recordDate,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.transaction_total,
  base_account.random_table_name_transaction.view_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_view.user_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_view.view_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_view.new_vs_returning,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.view_id,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.experienceId,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.experienceName,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.variationName,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.iterationId,
  base_account.random_table_name_experience.isControl
FROM
  `base_account.random_table_name_transaction` transactiontable
INNER JOIN
  base_account.random_table_name_view viewtable
ON
  transactiontable.view_id=viewtable.view_id
INNER JOIN
  `base_account.random_table_name_experience` experiencetable
ON
  viewtable.view_id=experiencetable.view_id
WHERE experiencetable.experienceId = 96659 OR experiencetable.experienceId = 96660;
```

Note that the only changes I made were to put the `#standardSQL` at the start (to enable standard SQL) and to escape the table names with backticks rather than brackets.

Comment: @eliot-brossard I added your fixes and I was returned `"Cannot reference a Legacy SQL view in a SQL query."`

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to change the view definition to use standard SQL as well in that case. You can read suggestions about this in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#logical_views).