# Error on my JOIN in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join the data in one table with the corresponding match field in three other tables.

When I have one JOIN it works fine, but adding in the others I get the following error message:

> Field
>   'dtftv2_sprt_p_match_table_advertisers_166401._PARTITION_LOAD_TIME'
>   not found on either side of the JOIN

Here my Query at the moment:

```
SELECT
dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks.Date as Date,
dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_advertisers_166401.Advertiser as Advertiser,
dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_campaigns_166401.Campaigns as Campaign,
dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_placements_166401.Placements as Placement,
dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks.Clicks as Clicks

FROM [dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks]

INNER JOIN [dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_advertisers_166401] ON 
dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks.Advertiser_ID = 
dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_advertisers_166401.Advertiser_ID

INNER JOIN [dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_campaigns_166401] ON 
dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks.Campaign_ID = 
dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_campaigns_166401.Campaign_ID

INNER JOIN [dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_placements_166401] ON 
dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks.Placement_ID = 
dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_placements_166401.Placement_ID

GROUP BY
Date,
Advertiser,
Campaign,
Placement,
Clicks
```

I'm not linking the _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME anywhere so why is it kicking up a fuss? INNER JOINS the right ones to use?

Comment: Something looks off with this error. `dtftv2_sprt_p_match_table_advertisers_166401._PARTITION_LOAD_TIME` versus `dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_campaigns_166401.Campaign_ID` I'm not sure if this is a typo when the code and error were copied but looks like maybe one of the identifiers here is messed up. (note the underscore vs full stop)

Comment: That is the exact error and the exact code. Why I am also confused.

Comment: alias the tables and use the alias instead of the Fully Qualified Name.  I'm just curios what would happen.  This would reduce the occurrences of that name and allow you to focus in on a specific join/error.

Comment: Which one @xQbert, or all of them?

Comment: all of them; but it appears _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME is something specific:  to bigQuery https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x so I need to read up more on it.  May have something to do with how the tables in your system are created; and maybe there's a requirement to specify the partition when using p_match_table_advertisers_16640 table

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313588/error-field-redacted-field-id-not-found-on-either-side-of-the-join-googl

Comment: Is 166401 a partition of the table?  Regarding which join: That's up to you do you and your requirements.  Want only data that exists in all the tables or all data from one or two and related from others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying to limit the problem down to a join:  Perhaps it has something to do with the partitions of the tables created/used.  I don't know if the system can require information regarding which partition to use when executing a query..  Though, I've not seen a partition used like this before.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AC.Date as Date,
      TA.Advertiser as Advertiser,
      TC.Campaigns as Campaign,
      TP.Placements as Placement,
      AC.Clicks as Clicks
FROM `dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks` AC
INNER JOIN `dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_advertisers_166401` TA 
   ON AC.Advertiser_ID = TA.Advertiser_ID
INNER JOIN `dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_campaigns_166401` TC 
   ON AC.Campaign_ID = TC.Campaign_ID
INNER JOIN `dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_placements_166401` TP 
   ON AC.Placement_ID = TP.Placement_ID
GROUP BY Date,
         Advertiser,
         Campaign,
         Placement,
         Clicks
```

and perhaps back ticks instead of [] based on ["Error: Field '[REDACTED].field_id' not found on either side of the JOIN", Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313588/error-field-redacted-field-id-not-found-on-either-side-of-the-join-googl)

Comment: Perfect! Still odd why using Alias' bypassed the issue. For future reference, I will always try and use alias' when I can. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I can't say why it worked; I don't fully understand the problem myself!   Thought is' obvious it has to be with how the engine parses the SQL; I'm not familiar enough with BigQuery myself to know what's going on in this case; but I know reducing the scope of the problem allows me to isolate and in so doing sometimes solve.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you change the `[]` to backticks as well?  or just change the aliasing? what about the application of `#standardSQL`?  again trying to improve the question/answer better to help others.

Comment: I switched it over to the backticks, and used Standard SQL, usually I use Legacy SQL, but either way it works.

Comment: Added an update to have the Legacy SQL also, if anyone needed it.

Answer (score 0):

For reference purposes here is the Legacy SQL version also:

```
SELECT AC.Date as Date, 
       TA.Advertiser as Advertiser,
       TC.Campaign as Campaign,
       TP.Placement as Placement,
       AC.Clicks as Clicks

FROM [dtftv2_sprt.sprt_all_clicks] AC

INNER JOIN [dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_advertisers_166401] TA 
   ON AC.Advertiser_ID = TA.Advertiser_ID

INNER JOIN [dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_campaigns_166401] TC 
   ON AC.Campaign_ID = TC.Campaign_ID

INNER JOIN [dtftv2_sprt.p_match_table_placements_166401] TP 
   ON AC.Placement_ID = TP.Placement_ID

GROUP BY Date,
         Advertiser,
         Campaign,
         Placement,
         Clicks
```